# Pandas, sorting a dataframe in a useful way to find the difference between times. Why are key and value errors appearing?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, multiple-columns, rows

I have a pandas DataFrame containing 5 columns.

```
['date', 'sensorId', 'readerId', 'rssi']
df_json['time'] = df_json.date.dt.time
```

I am aiming to find people who have entered a store (rssi > 380). However this would be much more accurate if I could also check every record a sensorId appears in and whether the time in that record is within 5 seconds of the current record.

Data from the dataFrame: (df_json)

```
                       date  sensorId  readerId  rssi
0   2017-03-17 09:15:59.453   4000068        76   352
0   2017-03-17 09:20:17.708   4000068        56   374
1   2017-03-17 09:20:42.561   4000068        60   392
0   2017-03-17 09:44:21.728   4000514        76   352
0   2017-03-17 10:32:45.227   4000461        76   332
0   2017-03-17 12:47:06.639   4000046        43   364
0   2017-03-17 12:49:34.438   4000046        62   423
0   2017-03-17 12:52:28.430   4000072        62   430
1   2017-03-17 12:52:32.593   4000072        62   394
0   2017-03-17 12:53:17.708   4000917        76   335
0   2017-03-17 12:54:24.848   4000072        25   402
1   2017-03-17 12:54:35.738   4000072        20   373
```

I would like to use jezrael's answer of df['date'].diff(). However I cannot successfully use this, I receive many different errors. The ['date'] column is of dtype datetime64[ns].

How the data is stored above is not useful, for the .diff() to be of any use the data must be stored as below (dfEntered):

Sample Data: dfEntered

```
    date       sensorId readerId time            rssi
    2017-03-17 4000046  43       12:47:06.639000 364
                        62       12:49:34.438000 423
               4000068  56       09:20:17.708000 374
                        60       09:20:42.561000 392
                        76       09:15:59.453000 352
               4000072  20       12:54:35.738000 373
                                 12:54:42.673000 374
                        25       12:54:24.848000 402
                                 12:54:39.723000 406
                        62       12:52:28.430000 430
                                 12:52:32.593000 394
               4000236  18       13:28:14.834000 411
```

I am planning on replacing 'time' with 'date'. Time is of dtype object and I cannot seem to cast it or diff() it.'date' will be just as useful.

The only way (I have found) of having df_json appear as dfEntered is with: 
    dfEntered = df_json.groupby(by=[df_json.date.dt.time, 'sensorId', 'readerId', 'date'])

If I do:

```
dfEntered = df_json.groupby(by=[df_json.date.dt.time, 'sensorId', 'readerId'])['date'].diff()
```

results in:

```
File "processData.py", line 61, in <module>
dfEntered = df_json.groupby(by=[df_json.date.dt.date, 'sensorId', 'readerId', 'rssi'])['date'].diff()
  File "<string>", line 17, in diff
  File "C:\Users\danie\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 614, in wrapper
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

If I do:

```
dfEntered = df_json.groupby(by=[df_json.date.dt.date, 'sensorId', 'readerId', 'rssi'])['time'].count()
print(dfEntered['date'])
```

Results in:

```
File "processData.py", line 65, in <module>
    print(dfEntered['date'])
  File "C:\Users\danie\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\danie\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 821, in get_value
    raise e1
KeyError: 'date'
```

I applied a .count() to the groupby just so that I can output it. I had previously tried a .agg({'date':'diff'}) which resluts in the valueError, but the dtype is datetime64[ns] (atleast in the original df_json, I cannot view the dtype of dfEntered['date']

If the above would work I would like to have a df of [df_json.date.dt.date, 'sensorId', 'readerId', 'mask'] mask being true if they entered a store.

I then have the below df (contains sensorIds that received a text)

```
   sensor_id sms_status                date_report  rssi  readerId
0    5990100    SUCCESS 2017-05-03 13:41:28.412800   500  10
1    5990001    SUCCESS 2017-05-03 13:41:28.412800   500  11
2    5990100    SUCCESS 2017-05-03 13:41:30.413000   500  12
3    5990001    SUCCESS 2017-05-03 13:41:31.413100   500  13
4    5990100    SUCCESS 2017-05-03 13:41:34.413400   500  14
5    5990001    SUCCESS 2017-05-03 13:41:35.413500   500  52
6    5990100    SUCCESS 2017-05-03 13:41:38.413800   500  60
7    5990001    SUCCESS 2017-05-03 13:41:39.413900   500  61
```

I would then like to merge the two together on day, sensorId, readerId.
I am hoping that would result in a df that could appear as [df_json.date.dt.date, 'sensorId', 'readerId', 'mask'] and therefore I could say that a sensorId with a mask of true is a conversion. A conversion being that sensorId received a text that day and also entered the store that day.

I'm beginning to get wary that my end aim isn't even achievable, as I simply do not understand how pandas works yet :D (damn errors)

**UPDATE**

```
dfEntered = dfEntered.reset_index()
```

This is allowing me to access the date and apply a diff.

I don't quite understand the theory of how this problem occurred, and why reset_index() fixed this.

Comment: It is a bit unclear `everyOtherRecord.contains(specifc ID)['time']-['time'] > 00:00:05` - can you add some data sample - 5-8 rows? Be free use my sample from my answer.

Comment: Can you add data to question by edit link, becasue bad formating of comments?

Comment: Haha I'm just as useless wiuh stackoverflow :) I very much like your answer, I would need to order my data in a different way though, right?

Comment: Very nice sample, thank you. What is desired output?

Comment: I'm still pondering on that. I just need to know that a sensorId did enter a shop (include readerID) and I would include time as well but at this point I don't need it. 

And maybe I'm crazy (haven't researched this far yet), I have another dataframe with sensorIds that received a text. I need to match those sensorIDs that received a text from a readerId to this dataframe.

So if someone received a text from reader 1 today, and also entered the store today, thats a conversion

Comment: OK, so need sort times first and then get difference for condition? It seems `df.groupby(by = [df.date.dt.date, 'sensorId', 'readerId', 
df.date.dt.time, 'rssi']).apply()` is not necessary, need working with `df` only. What is `print (df.head(8))` ?

Comment: I just see your all comment. If there is another dataframe, need data sample also.  What is `print (df_another.head(8))` ?

Comment: A lot of columns that I don't need, its a large dataframe read from json

Comment: Yiou can filter columns by `df = df[['col1','col2','col3','col 78']]` first.

Comment: Yeah I've been a little messy, the script has multiple grouped dfs for different reasons. Will start tidying it up. However with the current group, is your answer not still doing exactly what I want? The time difference between when the person was next pinged will be correct and I would follow your mask sample but include readerID and SensorID. Would that allow me to compare both dfs and say:
    if [(dfEntered['sensorId'] == df['sensorId']) & (['mask'] == True) & (df['readerID'] == dfEntered['readerId'])]

Comment: You need join both dataframes together before filtering - need [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) first.

Comment: Hard to know if it works without all data, but it seems you need `df = pd.merge(dfEntered, df, on=['sensorId','readerId'])` and then
`df = df[mask]`

Comment: Thank you very much jezrael, you've been so helpful.Unfortunately I cannot even get the df in the way that I would need it. 

I tidied it up and the df for entering a store only contains df = df[['sensorId','readerId','date','rssi']] and also ['time'] = df.date.dt.time

However because it is no longer grouped, it is not in the format as shown above, which results in .diff() finding the difference between two times that may be from a completely different person (sensorID)

I've literally spent the last few hours trying to have the df appear as above :(

Comment: Then I have idea. Try create 3 csv files, 2 input files with 10 rows and one output file what need get from both input files. Then send it to my email in my profile and together get solution. Now I am offline, (pn phone only) but yestwrday I try check it and find solution. Also if have some problem, better is communicate by email as by comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rssi': [500,530,1020,1201,1231,10], 
                   'time': pd.to_datetime(['2017-01-01 14:01:08','2017-01-01 14:01:14',
                                           '2017-01-01 14:01:17', '2017-01-01 14:01:27',
                                           '2017-01-01 14:01:29', '2017-01-01 14:01:30'])})
print (df)
   rssi                time
0   500 2017-01-01 14:01:08
1   530 2017-01-01 14:01:14
2  1020 2017-01-01 14:01:17
3  1201 2017-01-01 14:01:27
4  1231 2017-01-01 14:01:29
5    10 2017-01-01 14:01:30
```

---

```
print (df['time'].diff())
0        NaT
1   00:00:06
2   00:00:03
3   00:00:10
4   00:00:02
5   00:00:01
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

mask = (df['time'].diff() >'00:00:05')  & (df['rssi'] > 380)
print (mask)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool

df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
   rssi                time
1   530 2017-01-01 14:01:14
3  1201 2017-01-01 14:01:27
```

Comment: Think I'm almost there! Using your answer now :)

    df_entered['mask'] = (df_entered['rssi'] > 380) & ((df_entered['timediff'] > 5.0) | (df_entered['readerId'].diff().abs() == 0.0))

The above statement ends with the error: TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

I'm not exactly sure why this is occurring

Comment: It seems very nice, simpl;iest is not assign mask to ne column and use `mask = (df_entered['rssi'] > 380) & ((df_entered['timediff'] > 5.0) | (df_entered['readerId'].diff().abs() == 0.0))` and `df1 = df_entered[mask]`.

Comment: It seems there are some bad data - check [`dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) by `print (df.dtypes)`, `object` is obviously `string`.

Comment: using mask rather than ['mask'] worked. I've then done 

df_conversion = df_entered[['date', 'sensorId', 'readerId', 'mask']]

print(df_conversion.dtype)

Apparently df object has no attribute dtype, that seems like it might be a problem? 

I've only now realised you said merge both BEFORE creating mask, which makes a lot of sense... not currently the way I've gone

Comment: I think it is no problem, only I try only find some solution for your error. But if it works, it is really good. And I have to admire you that you get it ;)

Comment: Thought the merge was going to be the hardest part! All done, so happy!

df_conversion = df_conversion.merge(df_sms, on=['sensorId','readerId'], how='left')

Comment: supeeeeer :) Congrat ;)